# TikTok Web API invalid scope

Tags: node.js, oauth, scopes, tiktok, tiktok-api

I have successfully implemented the whole TikTok authentication process with the basic scope: basic.user.info.

However I can't add an additional scope (video.list), every time I go to the authorization page, TikTok returns an error saying that my scope is not valid.

I made sure I had access to this scope and my application is in production
.
I have separated my scopes with a comma as explained in the documentation

> A comma separated (,) string of authorization scope(s).

My URL currently looks like this:

```
https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_key=my_key&response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_url&scope=user.info.basic%2Cvideo.list&state=my_state
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank you for reading

Comment: Hi Thomas. How did you succesfully implemented the whole TikTok authentiction process ? I read that we need the app to be approved and running in production stage. Is that right ? Did you not encountered troubles with redirect_uri ? How did you solve that ?

Answer (score 2):

Thom! You need to add additional scopes for your app from the developers dashboard:  https://developers.tiktok.com/app/

[Additioanl scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3983G.png)